# extract load in div

Tags: javascript, html, load

i use this script that uses the load function and inserts it in a div

```js
<div id="NomeUtente"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#NomeUtente").load('http://www.ilfree.it/index.php?/nome.html/');
</script>
```

it is possible through php to draw in content within the div?
I wish I could pick up the result in the div and then use it on php... help me please

Comment: `$.post('yourpage.php', { data: $("#NomeUtente").html() })`?

Comment: I wish I could pick up the result in the div and then use it on php

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about what you mean by a php page. But you can read the contents of a div using jquery's [html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

```
   var htmlContent = $("#NomeUtente").html();
```